# Which is better if(a) or if(a!=NULL)

Tags: c++

if a is a pointer, is there a difference between testing if(a) and if(a != NULL) ? Which one is better?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis nevermind, baaaaaaad reading. My eyes skipped `if a is a pointer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. Use whichever makes your code more readable for yourself and others. If it's getting to verbose, or if the context is clear, feel free to omit the explicit NULL:

```
void * p = std::malloc(n);
if (!p) throw std::bad_alloc();
```

Comment: Normally, you should use `new` in c++, but I can't think of a better example myself.

Comment: @tstenner: Have you looked at writing your own `::operator new` by chance? Objects and memory are two separate, unrelated notions in C++. Don't confuse one with the other.

Comment: You're right, but people who write their own operators normally don't ask (yet) about the difference between if(a) and if(a!=null).

Comment: @tstenner: True, but people who use `new` and don't know about the non-throwing version shouldn't be checking for NULL, either! :-)

Comment: I think `if (dynamic_cast<D*>(p) != NULL)` would be a good non-allocation example.

Comment: Some libraries might have functions that return null (I think the MySQL-library does this).

Answer (score 5):

It's the same, but the second one makes your intent more clear.

If you're using C++11, you should use [nullptr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Null_pointer_constant), as it won't allow `int x; if(x==nullptr){...}`

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler will emit the same code for both, but `if(a)` is a perfectly normal C idiom and that's what your fellow programmers will expect to see.

Comment: Which fellow programmers?  There's a large group of C programmers who like obfuscation, but in C++, it's generally been either `if ( a != NULL )` or `if ( a != 0 )`.